# High School Math, Unit Circle, why is this negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

I'm having trouble understanding the solution

[image: Solution Image]

I don't understand how x^2 = 0.5 changes into x = - 1 / 2^0.5

[image: This part of the solution I'm stuck on]

Comment: Read the block of text, in particular: "But the point is in quadrant III, so $x$ is negative."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "in the quadrant III", $x<0$.

For $x^2=\frac{1}{2}$, there are two solutions:
$$
x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\quad x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
The second one is *negative*.